# Python Selenium not finding button on Firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm doing a guru99 exercise on Selenium, and I'm running into this error trying to click away the privacy agreement from the beginning:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.sys.mjs:8:8
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:182:5
NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.sys.mjs:394:5
element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.sys.mjs:134:16
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(
    "https://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/")

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='save']")))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='save']").click()
```

My syntax seems to be correct, so what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: PapaG PapaG  PapaG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The privacy agreement button is wrapped inside an IFRAME. You just need to switch into the IFRAME first, and then perform `click()` on the button.

Just use below code just before clicking on the button:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='gdpr-consent-notice']")))
```

Full working code FYR:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.demo.guru99.com/V4/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# below line switches into the IFRAME
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='gdpr-consent-notice']")))
# below line click the privacy agreement button
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='save']"))).click()
# below line switches back from iframe to main content
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Did not know about the frames.